# Oracle PL/SQL: Function Error when passing parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I pass a parameter to a function call, I get the following error:

> Error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'GET_NUM'.

The code is as follows:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TESTJNSABC IS

  -- FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATIONS
  FUNCTION get_num(num IN NUMBER) 
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    my_cursor VARCHAR2(20);
  BEGIN
    IF get_num = 1 THEN

      my_cursor:= 'hello world';
    ELSE
      my_cursor:= 'Hi!';
    END IF;

    RETURN my_cursor;

  END;

  -- PROCEDURE IMPLEMENTATIONS 
  PROCEDURE testingabc AS
    x NUMBER(3);
    BEGIN
      x:= 2;
        dbms_output.put_line(get_num(x));
      END testingabc;

END TESTJNSABC;
```

Comment: The issue is in `IF get_num = 1`; what do you expect this to do?

Comment: I'm just creating a simple example to view the functionality of functions and procedures. But if 1 is a NUMBER TYPE why I'm I getting this error?

Comment: He already answered you. on the IF statement you are calling the function itself, the error is because it isn't a recursive function and `get_num` needs a parameter. what you want is probably `IF num = 1 THEN` which is your parameter.

Comment: you are calling the function `get_num` without parameters, while it has one input parameter. What do you need to do with that line of code?

Comment: Yes your right! I beleived I vas comparing to "num", not to the get_num function itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an issue in `IF get_num = 1 THEN`, because you are calling the function `get_num` without parameters, while it has one input parameter

If you want to check the parameter value, you probably mean:

```
IF num = 1 THEN
```

Comment: I was about to ask you to add your comment as an answer. So I could give you a +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `IF get_num = 1`. The code will work after you change it to `IF num = 1`.

Entire sample code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TESTJNSABC IS

-- FUNCTION IMPLEMENTATIONS

FUNCTION get_num(num IN NUMBER) 
   RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   my_cursor VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
IF num = 1 THEN

  my_cursor:= 'hello world';
ELSE
  my_cursor:= 'Hi!';
END IF;

RETURN my_cursor;

END;

 -- PROCEDURE IMPLEMENTATIONS 
PROCEDURE testingabc AS
x NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
  x:= 2;
    dbms_output.put_line(get_num(x));
  END testingabc;

END TESTJNSABC;
```